# Resizing custom image marker with zoom - Google Maps API v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm using a custom image as an icon/marker for a Google Map API. I would like the marker image to resize as users zoom in on the map.

I adopted some of the code from this question: [Google Maps :: Changing icon based on zoom level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7047284/google-maps-changing-icon-based-on-zoom-level/13385598#13385598)

Unfortunately, this script only changes the last lat/long marker in my list. I'm not sure why, can anyone point out my mistake?

Here's the code:

```
var locations = [
 ['Aaron Baddeley (130)',-25.274398,133.775136],
 ['Adam Hadwin (176)',52.939916,-106.450864],
 ['Adam Scott (7)',-26.65,153.066667],
 ['Adilson da Silva (291)',-28.530554,30.895824],
 ['Alejandro Canizares (167)',40.416775,-3.70379],];

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({}

var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage('images/marker11.gif',
  new google.maps.Size(9,9), //size
    null, //origin
    null, //anchor
    new google.maps.Size(9,9) //scale
);

var marker, i;
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
  map: map,
  icon: image,
});

//when the map zoom changes, resize the icon based on the zoom level so the marker covers the same geographic area
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
  var pixelSizeAtZoom4 = 9; //the size of the icon at zoom level 4
  var maxPixelSize = 350; //restricts the maximum size of the icon, otherwise the browser will choke at higher zoom levels trying to scale an image to millions of pixels

  var zoom = map.getZoom();
  var relativePixelSize = Math.round(pixelSizeAtZoom4*Math.pow(1.2,zoom)); // use 2 to the power of current zoom to calculate relative pixel size.  Base of exponent is 2 because relative size should double every time you zoom in

  if(relativePixelSize > maxPixelSize) //restrict the maximum size of the icon
   relativePixelSize = maxPixelSize;

  if(zoom < 4) //when zooming < 4, fix pixel size to 9
   relativePixelSize = 9;


//change the size of the icon

marker.setIcon(
    new google.maps.MarkerImage(
        marker.getIcon().url,  //marker's same icon graphic
        null,//size
        null,//origin
        null, //anchor
        new google.maps.Size(relativePixelSize, relativePixelSize) //changes the scale
    )
);        
});
```

Comment: related question: [change google maps custom icon with zoom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18992074/change-google-maps-custom-icon-with-zoom)

Answer (score 0):

Add an event listener for `zoom_changed` events that trigger a change of the marker's icon

```
map.addListener('zoom_changed', function() {
    for (var i=0, len = locations.length; i < len; i++) { 
       // set new icon depending on the value of map.getZoom()
       markers[i].setIcon(...) 
    }
});
```

You should save your markers in an array `markers` when you create them in the for loop, so you can reference them as `markers[i]`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm pretty green when it comes to creating arrays, so I tried using a different approach, basically resizing the same marker depending on the zoom level.